# python: class namespace for simple decorator function

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am somewhat new to decorators in Python and are struggeling with a simple decorator, that is supposed to check for a state of my class (doing the operation once when one of the dependending functions is actually called for the first time). My problem is, that I want to let the decorator function also know about everything in self and pass the actual function as 'argument'(?)

```
class myClass(object):
    __init__(self):
        self.__isFoo = False
        self.__baz = 0

    def doFoo(self):
        ...  
        self.__isFoo = True

    def fooInit(self,func):
        if not self.__isFoo:
            self.doFoo()
        return func

    @property
    @fooInit
    def getBaz(self):
        return self.__baz
```

however, with this one, I get an error that

```
myObj = myClass()
myObj.getBaz

~~> TypeError: fooInit() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

which I somewhat understand, since it is just
    self.fooinit( self.getBaz )
if I understand decorators correctly, or?

So I am a bit lost now, how I can define the decorator in an easy way, that it also knows the other objects in the class namespace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decorating a class method after @property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923706/decorating-a-class-method-after-property)

Comment: This actually has to do with the fact that you're decorating a property. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: And remember, your arguments to the decorator are actually going to be ``(func, *args, **kwargs)``, where ``args[0]`` is going to be ``self``. Generally speaking, the [decorator functions](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) themselves aren't defined as part of the class name-space.

Comment: And you have to remember to call the passed in function as well. Decorators are just syntactic sugar around writing ``wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs)``, where ``func`` will always be the decorated function. They don't change python's call mechanics at all.

Comment: You have a typo which missing `def` before `__init__(self)`

Comment: @aruisdante thanks for the duplicate link and the suggestions

Comment: however, it seems that I still struggle with the decorator vs. namespace wrapping even when omitting the @property decorator. I.e., I still would rely on fooInit to be in the classes namespace,


    def fooInit(self,func):
        def _wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if not self.doFoo:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapped
if you are right and a decorator cannot be defined within the class namespace I have to find another way (without the syntactic sugar) :-/

Comment: @aruisdante sorry for the noise -- finally I got it.
self will be the first of the *args arguments...

took a while for me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following @aruisdante's suggestions I managed to get a proper decorator working

```
def fooInit(func):
    def _wrapped(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if not self.__isFoo:
            self.fooInit()
            return func(self,*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped
```

(defined within my class)