# Memoize decorator not returning actual value

Tags: python

I have this `memoize` decorator:

```
import functools

cache = {}

def memoize(obj):
    @functools.wraps(obj)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[args]
    return memoizer
```

which works pretty fine with any method of the class. However, it gives the following error when used with a `@property` decorator.

`AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute '__module__'`

How do I make it work with a `@property` method of a class?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**:

```
class QClass(object):
    @memoize
    @property
    def positive(self):
        return Predicate('positive')
```

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923706/decorating-a-class-method-after-property) help?

Comment: I'm not sure. Let me try few things from there.

Comment: Hmm i'm guessing this has to do with how functools.wraps copies over __module__ and other things for you.  Can I see the context of what you're doing when you say you're using it along with @property?

Answer (score 0):

As `property` object miss `__module__` and other attributes, you should apply its decorator as the last one:

```
class QClass(object):
    @property
    @memoize
    def positive(self):
        return Predicate('positive')
```

Or alternatively specify in memoize decorator available attributes for an assignment:

```
def memoize(obj):
    @functools.wraps(obj, assigned=('__doc__',))
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        …
```

Answer (score 0):

This was answered by a colleague of mine.

The decorator can be written like this:

```
from functools import update_wrapper
predicate_cache = {}

def cached_property(cache):
    """Create a property, where the lookup is stored in ``cache``"""
    def decorator(method):
        name = method.__name__
        def wrapper(self):
            if name not in cache:
                cache[name] = method(self)
            return cache[name]   
        return property(update_wrapper(wrapper, method))
    return decorator
```

And it can be used like this:

```
predicate_cache = {}

class QClass(object):
    @cached_property(predicate_cache)
    def positive(self):
        """..."""
        return Predicate("positive")
```